# IE 9 Crashes on my website

Tags: internet-explorer-9

My website crashes in Internet Explorer 9 but works fine in Firefox and Chrome. Homepage loads fine in IE but any post pages crash, for example on my contact page: http://www.poker006.com/2008/02/contact-me.html

I don't know if it's just my version of Internet Explorer or something wrong with the code on my site.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check your page with the [HTML-Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.poker006.com/2008/02/contact-me.html). It has 281 errors and 302 warnings.

Comment: Even Google has 34 Errors, 2 warning(s). How do you know if you have a major issue?

Comment: @user1362534: Clean up your own code. If google fails, that's their problem. If your code matches the specification, and the browser collapses still, blame the browser. But not before. Yes, of course the browser should sanitize against malicious code, but maybe that's not always that easy.

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly fine for me, in IE9:

[image]

I would recommend adding a conditional comment to your page:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
     <!--This will alert anyone using IE8 and below-->
       <script>
         alert("Please Update Your Browser");
       </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

You can also redirect them:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
     <!--This will redirect anyone using IE8 and below-->
      meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/products/ie/home">
    <![endif]-->
```

Or, of course, both:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
     <!--This will alert & redirect anyone using IE8 and below-->
       <script>
         alert("Please Update Your Browser");
       </script>
      meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/products/ie/home">
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I wouldn't want to redirect visitors and maybe they do not want to update right away. Btw, that code didn't work but I tried this and it worked:

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script>alert("Please upgrade to the latest version of Internet Explorer!");</script>
<![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

It could be an add-on or something you installed for your IE that is causing an issue. Go to your homepage, press F12 for Developer tool, then click on Script and press Start. Go to that URL to see any errors with your page.

Your site looks like it's created with Wordpress. Shouldn't be any major issues with specific browser, or else you will see it.

Comment: I disabled all add-ons and reinstalled ie and my site no longer crashes. I created the site on blogger.